# How to set Firebase cloud functions to route to Firestore instead of Realtime Database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a firebase project on android. I originally set up a realtime database, then attempted to add cloud functions, but decided to switch to firestore.

I added a firestore database, but the cloud functions would not route there and instead added to the RTDB. I disabled the RTDB and started getting the error that the "database ___ has been disabled by the owner".

I have resulted reverting my code back to before I set up cloud functions, and re set it up with only the Firestore available. It still tries to write to the RTDB even though it is disabled (still shows in console though).

How do I route it to firestore? Thanks

For reference, I used [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) to add cloud functions

EDIT: Problem solved, I should have been using Firestore triggers, found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

Comment: Go through your code base and remove all mentions of `firebase.database()` and `admin.database()`. Then work through your code and change your code from the RTDB API to use the Cloud Firestore API using `firebase.firestore()` and `admin.firestore()`.

Comment: Here is the [Cloud Firestore API](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/) for the Admin SDK. Instead of using `new Firestore()` from `@google-cloud/firestore`, use `admin.firestore()` in it's place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "routing". You have to use the API provided by the database you want to use.  Realtime Database and Firestore are completely differere database products, and they don't have the same API or SDK. So if you switch to Firestore, you will have to rewrite all your code to use its SDK instead of Realtime Database.

Comment: I see. I wasn't able to find another way to do it through firestore, could you point me to the firestore API for functions?

Comment: Use the Firebase Admin SDK, or the nodejs SDK for Firestore provided by Google Cloud. The Admin SDK just wraps the same API provided by the Cloud SDK.

Comment: Yup, you were originally right, I should have been using Firestore triggers. Thank you!